# How do I create startup code for longrunning azure functions?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I plan to create a functions project that is always running, but responds to multiple triggers as per azure functions.

I know this can be done with webjobs, but can it be done with functions? If so how do I hook up a startup file as entry point for the longrunning (blocking) background task?

Comment: How long? Functions can only run for 10 minutes (recently up from 5).

Comment: Durable Functions has been released recently, which are suitable for long-running jobs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact point of Azure Functions is that they only run in response to events. If no events occur, they don't run.

Functions are not a good match for always-running background processes.

Answer (score 2):

Please note, that Azure functions have a runtime hard limit of 10 minutes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale.

That means, you should plan your function to only react to the different events, process it and is then disposed. Depending on your use case, you should consider other options - maybe you can tell some more about the goal you want to achieve.

Comment: Certainly. I mainly want to process events, but I am dependent on having a lot of data in memory (roughly 4 mb = 14k objects ), and I will process events every 4 seconds in average. That means I either need to read 4 mb, process event and update the state by writing 4 mb to blob/table, or to go for a continuously running process where I have everything in memory.

Comment: Okay, then maybe something more "persistent" - like a VM or Web App - will suit your requirements better.
That sounds a little bit like a streaming / monitoring project to me - as I don't know why you should process the 14k objects over and over again. But maybe take a look at PowerBI Integration in the event hub - it offers live analysis on the streamed data - maybe it is possible to crunch and fetch necessary data there also.

Comment: If you only need the long-running process to cache data, maybe try Redis.

Comment: Also, the 10 minute window only applies to the Consumption plan. If you use an App Service plan, your jobs can be as long as you want.